# How to create a class with a static pointer to a dynamic array?

Tags: c++

I want to define a Class, which contains a static pointer to a dynamic array, looks like

```
class MyStruct
{
    public:
        static int n;
        static int *pArr;
};
```

Here, `n` is an input variable which is dynamically defined. `pArr` is a pointer to an array with size `n`. The problem I encountered now is that static variable should be initialized when compiling, however, I don't know the value of `n` at this stage.

Comment: static variables are initialized to zero when the first object of the class is created

Comment: Well, you just have to initialize whenever you figure out what `n` should be, then you initialize it at that time. And you will need to structure your code so that `pArr` is only used after it is initialized. There is no special trick to this, this is all pretty much straightforward, fundamental C++. P.S. If your intent is to actually learn C++, you will use `std::vector` instead of this rudimentary, C-like approach; with `std::vector` taking care of all of these little details for you.

Comment: @JohnKugelman My end goal is to create a lot of objects defined by this class, and these objects share the same variable ```n``` and ```pArr```.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you very much for your comments. I'll change to use STL vector soon.

Comment: Why did you choose to make the class data attributes (n, and pArr) static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> static variable should be initialized when compiling, however, I don't
>   know the value of n at this stage.

Here is an example to illustrate 2 options available to you.  This code compiles and runs.

Notes:

1) class "MyStruct_t" uses default ctor/dtor.

2) In my practice, the suffix '_t' distinguishes a user defined type.

3) MyStruct_t::exec() receives argc and argv to demo the use of command line parameters to select pArr size.

4) When no command line parameters are entered (argc < 2), exec() invokes a stub function "MyStruct_t::determine_array_size()".

---

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl;

#include <cstdint>

#include <cstdlib>
using std::strtoul;

#include <cassert>


class MyStruct_t
{
   static unsigned long  n;
   static uint* pArr;

public:
   // use default ctor, dtor

   int exec(int argc, char* argv[])
      {
         if (argc > 1)
         {
            // array size passed in as command line parameter
            char* end;
            n = strtoul(argv[1], &end, 10);
            // assert(no range error);
            assert(n > 0); // if no conversion possible, 0 is returned
                           // asserts when user enters 0
         }
         else
         {
            // function to compute array size from tbd
            // see stub below
            n = determine_array_size();
         }

         assert(n > 0); // array size must be positive, i.e. > 0

         // now ok to allocate dynamic array
         pArr = new uint[n];

         // init pArr with uninteresting data, easy to validate
         for (uint i=0; i<n; ++i)
            pArr[i] = i+1;

         // show pArr for validation
         show();

         return 0;
      }

   void show()
      {
         cout << "\n   n:    "  << n << "\n";
         for (uint i=0; i<n; ++i)
            cout << "\n  [" << i << "]    " << pArr[i];
         cout << endl;
      }

private:    
   // stub for debug and code development
   uint determine_array_size()
      {
         // do 'what ever' to figure out array size -
         // prompt? read a file? count something? etc.
         return 5;
      }

}; // class MyStruct_t

// declare and init static parameters
unsigned long MyStruct_t::n    = 0;
uint*         MyStruct_t::pArr = nullptr;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   MyStruct_t myStruct;  // instantiate object

   return myStruct.exec(argc, argv); // use it
}
```

---

Output when no command line parameter

```
   n:    5

  [0]    1
  [1]    2
  [2]    3
  [3]    4
  [4]    5
```

Output when 1st command line parameter is 7 (others are ignored)

```
   n:    7

  [0]    1
  [1]    2
  [2]    3
  [3]    4
  [4]    5
  [5]    6
  [6]    7
```

Comment: @jwyan1126 - Why did you choose to make the class attributes (n, and pArr) static?  The code example I provide works the same if you remove 'static' and the initialization of the two.  WIthout the static modifier, you could instantiate multiple instances, each with the same or different size.

Comment: The function "MyStruct_t::show()" is an example of choosing "tell, don't ask".  Code that uses the data attributes of a class, for example to display info, should be bundled with the class and accessed with a public function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ```n``` and ```pArr``` are set to static because I hope each object instantiated from the class can access the array pointed by ```pArr```(pArr is very large, so it is not possible to save a copy for each object).

Comment: @jwyan1126 - Acceptable reason for the static.  Now, why did you choose an array rather than a static vector.  With a vector, you can discard 'n' and use vector<T>::size().

Comment: I choose an array rather than STL vector<T> because a further Fourier transform needs to perform on this array. In the fftw3 library, from my knowledge, it only accepts a classical c++ array as input.

Comment: I am confident you will not find 1) any performance problem with vectors (vs an array),  nor 2) confusion with parameter passing to functions using 'classical c++ array' parameters (by which I think you mean c-style parameters)  See  cppReference.com, std::vector:  "The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets to regular pointers to elements. This means that a pointer to an element of a vector may be _passed to any function that expects a pointer to an element of an array_."  I recommend you use vector.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting something like:

```
class MyStruct {
   // better have private members
        static int n;
        static int *pArr;
    public:
        static void init(int size) {
           n = size;
           pArr = new int[n]; // must be sure to delete this somewhere
        }
};

// in a .cpp file - must define your static members
int MyStruct::n; // default 0
int* MyStruct::pArr; // default nullptr
```